# Enumerating Items inside the multirow TABLE

Tags: tables, enumerate, multirow

After enumerating the cells, I get errors. I do not have any problems when I use the bullets. So, I am sure about the table structure, but wondering why I get errors when I use numbers! Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%% document setup
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%times new roman
%_______________%__________________________________________
%%to breack down line in a table
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont
\caption{AB}
\vskip .25in
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{tabular}{|p{.7cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{5.3cm}|p{4cm}|}\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
& A & B & C & D\vspace{.2cm}\\\hline
\multirow {3}{*}{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{E~\cite{for example}}}} 
&\vspace{.2cm} A\vspace{.2cm} & B & \multirow{3}{*}{
{
\begin{enumerate}
\item {tttt}
\item {wwww}
\end{enumerate}
}
}
& \multirow{3}{*}{
\begin{enumerate}
\item {iii}
\end{enumerate}
}\\\cline{2-3}
&C & D &&  \\\cline{2-3}
&\pbox{1.6cm}{E} & F && \\\hline
\end{tabular}\quad
\label{tab:ten}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any list -- `itemize`, `enumerate` or `description` used in table had to be `parbox` like cell, for example in `p{...}`. all columns in your table are such, however your list is `multirow` cell, which has different cell type:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{ ... }
```

which consider column formatting (`p{...}`) not consider column formatting but `l` cell (column) type. if you will replace existed multrow commands with

```
\multirow{2}{=}{ ... }
```

and have installed recent version of `multirow` packages, your mwe will work as expected.